# Unable to generate SHA1 Certificate

Tags: java, flutter, gradlew

I am customizing a Flutter app on VS Code that I purchased. I am trying to run the following command: "gradlew signingReport" but I get the below error. NOTE: I am running this command from within the android folder of the source code, please help me, thanks

This is the error I am getting below

gradlew : The term 'gradlew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- gradlew signingReport
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gradlew:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout this command:

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

Comment: Thank you Abbos, I managed to get it to work.